# count repeated terms in prolog

Tags: count, prolog

I want to ask about prolog programming. I have:

```
byCar(auckland,hamilton).
byCar(valmont,metz).

byTrain(metz,frankfurt).

byPlane(frankfurt,bangkok).
byPlane(bangkok,auckland).

travell(From,To,go(From,To,car)) :- byCar(From,To).
travell(From,To,go(From,To,train)) :- byTrain(From,To).
travell(From,To,go(From,To,plane)) :- byPlane(From,To).
travell(From,To,go(From,Step,Via,Go)) :- travell(From,Step,go(From,Step,Via)),travell(Step,To,Go).
```

Then I ask in winprolog:

```
?- travell(valmont,hamilton,Go).
```

It answered

```
Go = go(valmont,metz,car,go(metz,frankfurt,train,go(frankfurt,bangkok,plane,go(bangkok,auckland,plane,go(auckland,hamilton,car)))))
```

My question is, is it possible to count how many 'go' it have? like my example before it has 5 'go'

Answer (score -1):

would be easier if you could uniform go/3 and go/4 arity. Anyway, try

```
count_last_arg(Struct,Func,Count) :-
     count_last_arg(Struct,Func,0,Count).

count_last_arg(Struct,Func,N,Count) :-
     Struct =.. L, last(L, LL), LL =.. [Func|_]
  -> N1 is N+1,
     count_last_arg(LL,Func,N1,Count)
  ;  Struct =.. [Func|_]
  -> Count is N+1
  ;  Count is N.
```

Comment: hmm.... my knowledge is not up till this level yet... is there no other simpler way? anyway i will try...